# How to customize cmake output

Tags: cmake, build-system

For example, when compiling .c files, I want cmake to just print

```
CC    xxx.c
```

to stdout, like linux kbuild.

Answer (score 9):

CMake output can be customized by suppressing the standard messages produced by CMake and outputting a custom message in a launcher script instead. Add the following code to your outermost `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_MESSAGES OFF)
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/custom_output.sh")
```

Setting the global [RULE_MESSAGES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/RULE_MESSAGES.html) property to `OFF` will suppress the standard messages.
The global [RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE.html) property is set to a custom launch script named `custom_output.sh` which needs to be added to the root of the CMake source tree:

```
#!/bin/sh

# shell script invoked with the following arguments
# $(CXX) $(CXX_DEFINES) $(CXX_FLAGS) -o OBJECT_FILE -c SOURCE_FILE

# extract parameters
SOURCE_FILE="${@: -1:1}"
OBJECT_FILE="${@: -3:1}"

echo "CC $(basename \"$SOURCE_FILE\")"

# invoke compiler
exec "$@"
```

The script's executable bit needs to be set.

The linker output can be customized in the same fashion by also setting a [RULE_LAUNCH_LINK](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RULE_LAUNCH_LINK.html) script.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in the current version of `CMake`, without editing the source yourself.  Of course `sed` and `awk` will help you.