# CMake run custom command after target fails to build

Tags: build, cmake

I know how to run a command after (or before) building a target with add_custom_command :

```
add_custom_command(TARGET my_target POST_BUILD    
    COMMAND echo "custom command"      
)
```

But I want to ALWAYS run this command, **after the target has been build or after it failed to build**.

Here, when the target fails to build, the command is not launched.

Is it possible to achieve this with cmake?

Comment: The answer would depend on what you want to do. Can you give an example of a `POST_BUILD` step you want to do even when the build fails? Generally speaking - for makefile generators - you are doing something like ignoring the compiler/linker return values in CMake not by using `add_custom_command()` but using e.g. the [`RULE_LAUNCH_LINK`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/RULE_LAUNCH_LINK.html) global/directory/target property. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765547/how-to-customize-cmake-output).

Comment: I want to copy files with the cp command. I don't want to use an external script just be able to run a cp command each time after the build tails or succeeds.

Comment: Ok, is the file you want to copy an output of your build process and/or an input to another build step? This would be important to setup the dependency checking correctly. And - if we e.g. are talking about makefiles and you don't want to use external scripts - you probably still need to do something like `make -i` (see [here](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2009-October/032454.html)). Or maybe you can give an `makefile` code snippet of what you expect CMake to generate.