# CMake , don't print directory when compiling process

Tags: cmake

I recently updated my project to CMake, one thing is annoying. When building source files it prints the directory where object files are saved.

```
[ 13%] Building CXX object a/CMakeFiles/a.dir/src/A.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object b/CMakeFiles/b.dir/src/B.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object c/CMakeFiles/c.dir/src/C.cpp.o
```

I want to make it like this

```
[ 13%] Building CXX object A.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object B.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object C.cpp.o
```

I can't find anything about this.

Comment: AFAIK the piece of code that prints this is [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/v3.8.1/Source/cmNinjaTargetGenerator.cxx#L666), line is `description << "Building " << lang << " object $out";` and it seems `$out` is the relative path for object, that is then passed to gcc unmodified. So I don't expect to find a config option for that. Are you looking after a sort of filter to apply (in your terminal) to cmake output?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765547/how-to-customize-cmake-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Hugues Moreau commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903193/cmake-dont-print-directory-when-compiling-process#comment74980898_43903193) those texts are directly coded into CMake and can't be modified.

You could - without utilizing another script parsing your command line or output -
 only suppress the output with setting global [`RULE_MESSAGES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/RULE_MESSAGES.html) property to `OFF` and adding your own `echo` call.

*NOTE:*

1. It omits the percentage and color information also
2. It works only for [`Makefiles` generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#makefile-generators)

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(HelloWorld)

if(CMAKE_GENERATOR MATCHES "Makefiles")
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_MESSAGES OFF)
    set(
        CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT 
        "$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E echo Building <LANGUAGE> object $(@F)" 
        "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT}"
    )
endif()    

add_executable(HelloWorld main.cpp)
```

**References**

- [GNU Make - Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)

Comment: This replaces the output with 'Building C object A.cpp.o'. However it doesn't keep the `[ %14]` progress at the start.

Comment: Oh whoops, you mentioned that in your answer.